# Consecutive limits of a sequence of functions

Tags: undefined

I want to write two consecutive limits `$\displaystyle{\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}{\lim\limits_{N\to\+\infty}$`, but it doesn't work. Can someone offer some help, please?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean "doesn't work"?  The code between the `$`s has four opening braces, but only two closing braces -- these must match.  Perhaps you mean `$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\lim\limits_{N\to+\infty}$`?  Also, `\displaystyle` implies limits, so those are redundant.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** *Thank you very much for the suggestion of the user @Stephen.*

Your question is very general without a MWE....You have done a mix :-) of commands using `\limits` or (if you prefer) `\displaystyle`. Here there is a small example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\lim\limits_{N\to+\infty\vphantom{x\to 1^-}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

***Edit 2*: from second comment of @Stephen:** It is possible to use `\adjustlimits` command from `mathtools` package. Here there is another MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\adjustlimits\lim_{x\to 1^-}\lim_{N\to+\infty}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe even `$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\lim\limits_{N\to+\infty\vphantom{x\to 1^-}}$` for vertical alignment/prettification.

Comment: @Stephen You are absolutely right. In truth I had seen that there was not a correct alignment. Now I change and add your comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: ...and alternatively the mathtools package provides: `$\adjustlimits\lim_{x\to 1^-}\lim_{N\to+\infty}$`.

Comment: @Stephen Hi, it is true...in my bookmarks there is a question exactly to remember me this command. Thank you again but I have finished the upvotes :-(((( today.